# Waiting for multiple Firebase calls in parallel

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am developing a character generator for an RPG system as a way of learning Angular. I have my data in Firebase, which I am also new to.

When entering the creation form I want to load all data from types, descriptors and foci before I continue. My current solution, which does work, looks like this.

Character service:

```
var types = new Firebase(URL + '/Types');
var descriptors = new Firebase(URL + '/Descriptors');
var foci = new Firebase(URL + '/Foci');
...

allTypes: function()
{
    return $firebaseArray(types);
},
allDescriptors: function()
{
    return $firebaseArray(descriptors);
},
allFoci: function()
{
    return $firebaseArray(foci);
},
```

Character controller:

```
vm.types = Character.allTypes();
vm.descriptors = Character.allDescriptors();
vm.foci = Character.allFoci();
...

vm.types.$loaded(function() {
    vm.selectedType = vm.types[0];
    vm.descriptors.$loaded(function()
    {
        vm.selectedDescriptor = vm.descriptors[0];
        vm.foci.$loaded(function()
        {
            vm.selectedFocus = vm.foci[0];
            vm.skills.$loaded(function()
            {
                vm.abilities.$loaded(function()
                {
                    vm.ready = true;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This nested block looks really messy to me. How would I write this to load all the data in parallel? I tried using `$q.all` but it didn't seem to wait for anything to load at all. I don't have much experience with promises or asynchronous programming so many of the solutions I've read seem a little overwhelming.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$q.all** should work if they use Angulars **$q**, but i'm not really sure if they do.

It's normally used like this

```
$q.all([vm.descriptors.$loaded, vm.foci.$loaded, vm.skills.$loaded])
    .then(function() {
        console.log('all resolved');
    });
```

If this doesn't work you could wrap their promises with **$q** yourself:

```
var descriptorsDeferred = $q.defer();
var fociDeferred = $q.defer();
var skillsDeferred = $q.defer();

$q.all( [descriptorsDeferred.promise, fociDeferred.promise, skillsDeferred.promise] )
  .then( function ()
  {
    console.log( 'all resolved' );
  } );

vm.descriptors.$loaded()
  .then( function ()
  {
    descriptorsDeferred.resolve();
  } );

vm.foci.$loaded()
  .then( function ()
  {
    fociDeferred.resolve();
  } );

vm.skills.$loaded()
  .then( function ()
  {
    skillsDeferred.resolve();
  } );
```

Comment: Your first version is what I had tried before based on other examples, but it immediately prints the message without waiting. Your second suggestion works just like it should. Thank you!